# Pyinstaller, NameError: global name 'quit' is not defined

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script which runs just fine, however after running pyinstaller, I get the following when I use a `quit()` or `exit()` command:

Makespec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis([os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'support/_mountzlib.py'), os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'support/useUnicode.py'), 'icinga.py'],
             pathex=['/home/user/projects/icinga_python/releases/onefile_v1.0'])
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE( pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'icinga'),
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=1 )
```

Here is what I see after I run the app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 222, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 207, in main
  File "<string>", line 66, in icinga_mysql
  File "<string>", line 45, in checksanity
NameError: global name 'quit' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you post the line from the stack trace which is giving the error?  Looks to be line 207.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is because there is no `quit` command. You are looking for [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Comment: in a raw python program those two commands have two different behavior. Accttualy I'm using `quit()` to finish one thread and sys.exit would finish the entire process.Is there a way to still use `quit()`?

Answer (score 2):

`quit` can be found in pygame.locals import *

Usage:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def quit():
    sys.exit()


self.quit_button = Button(self, text="QUIT",command = quit)
```

Comment: Can you describe this code in words? What's the benefit of `def quit():` versus `command = sys.exit`?