# Name 'Quit' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

I looked here:

[Pyinstaller, NameError: global name 'quit' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474291/pyinstaller-nameerror-global-name-quit-is-not-defined])

but I still get "`name 'Quit' is not defined`" in my program.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

import pygame

def run_game():

    # initialize game and create screen object.

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Ship_left")

    # Set the background color.
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    # main loop of the game:
    while True:

        # keyboard and mouse events:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == Quit:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # draw the screen each time from new.
        screen.fill(bg_color)

        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Any ideas? I can't run my program.

Thanks.

Comment: `pygame.Quit` instead of just `Quit` unless you import `Quit` directly i.e. `from pygame import Quit`

Comment: You're referring to a variable named `Quit` but you haven't defined it anywhere nor imported it from another module, so of course it is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The `QUIT` constant (note: should be all caps) needs to be explicitly imported:

```
from pygame.locals import QUIT
```

Or, if you want all constants

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

though the latter is not recommended.

Alternatively, you could instead at every reference type `pygame.QUIT`

Comment: Why three points less? I've searched for it, didn't get an answer.

Comment: Only want to know for next time what not to post.

Comment: Well, this question is impossible to google, so we get a lot of these here on SO despite it not really being a programming problem. Remember than in python, you need to explicitly import *everything* you use in the file, witch the exception of `import *`

Comment: Basically, it got downvoted for being a but too much of a beginner question, if you keep learning you will soon have nothing to worry about

Comment: I'll have to notice through time what is good and what is bad to post... try better next time.